# Can we send SMS data with Twilio?

Tags: android, sms, twilio

I have an android studio application, the application use a BroadcastReceiver and

```
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED")
```

Now I'm trying to send  DATA SMS (Bytes) to this application using Twilio.

I do not know if it is posible or not, I need help please

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I'm aware, you can't send a data SMS message using the Twilio API. You can only send text messages (SMS) and (in the US and Canada) media messages (MMS).